# Мокрыми печальными птицами

Tags: падежи

> Можно, конечно, **мокрыми печальными птицами** сидеть тут, ожидая момента, пока вода спадёт, но, во-первых, она реально фонила, а во-вторых, неизвестно ещё, кто к нам приплывет снизу.

Я понял бы это как *Можно, конечно, сидеть тут, как мокрые печальные птицы (...)*

Можно ли всегда использовать творительный падеж в таком смысле, например:

> Он дрался за выживание львом.
>
> Он дрался за выживание как лев.

Answer (score 6):

Категорического запрета нет, но при использовании творительного падежа возможна двусмысленность. Например, в вашем примере "Он дрался за выживание львом", у меня первое впечатление от фразы было будто он использовал льва как оружие в драке. В меньшей степени двуссмысленность проявляется при изменении порядка слов, *Он львом дрался за выживание*, поэтому в таких конструкциях слово в творительном падеже **всегда** должно стоять рядом со сказуемым.

> **Я волком бы выгрыз** бюрократизм.
>   К мандатам почтения нету.
>   К любым чертям с матерями катись
>   любая бумажка. Но эту...

В. В. Маяковский "Стихи о советском паспорте" 1929 г.

Comment: А почему всегда? Чем плохо "реветь белугой", "нырять рыбкой" или "низвергаться стремительным домкратом"?

Comment: @Alex_ander да, спасибо подправил.

Answer (score 3):

Даже затрудняюсь объяснить какое тут правило действует, но почему-то всегда говорят *дрался как лев*, а вот, например, *юркнул ужом* - вполне нормально. В общем, тут всё зависит от глагола.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по внешним признакам, *обстоятельство образа действия* с использованием существительных в тв. падеже должно однозначно *связываться с глаголом* - от этого зависит сама возможность построения фразы. В предложении "Он дрался за выживание львом" связь с глаголом не просматривается и смысл "дрался (как?) подобно льву" утерян полностью (возникает вопрос: что за "выживание львом" - превратился во льва и выжил?). В то же время, при другом порядке слов смысл можно поправить, хотя по стилю выражение останется не совсем удачным: "он львом дрался за выживание" - это уже понятно (дрался храбро как лев), хотя изящества этому выражению сам приём не даёт. Возможно, для стилистических ограничений имеет значение сочетаемость (или даже идиоматическая связь) глагола с используемыми существительными: птицы сидят, волки грызут добычу...

```
Я волком бы выгрыз бюрократизм... (В. Маяковский)
```

Вывод такой: фразу таким способом можно построить практически всегда, но не всегда она будет выглядеть естественной.